# Will treating the edges of laminate parquet flooring with teak oil improve water resistance?

Tags: floor, waterproofing, hardwood-floor, laminate-floor, parquet

Recently, I bought laminate wood parquet flooring (8mm) with an HDF core for my apartment.  I intend to use this throughout the entire apartment, excluding bathrooms but including kitchen.  It is not rated as waterproof. The shop I bought it from told me that water issues of the parquet always comes from water seeping through the grooves between each plank and through the locking mechanism and reaching the HDF core.  To help with increasing the water resistance of the floor, he told me that I can treat the locking mechanism with teak oil.

I talked with my installer, and he said that has never done this or heard of it.  I got a bit confused.  It is a bit of an extra effort to paint each and every plank with teak oil, and I would like to know if it makes sense.  I've tried googling it, but did not find any definitive answer.

I've highlighted in orange the image below, to show where the shop told me to treat with teak oil.

[image: Treating with teak oil (highlighted in orange)]

Any ideas if it does help to treat with teak oil?  Are there any issues about doing this?  I'm also concerned that the floor might be stuck together, and cannot be taken apart easily if I need to change some of it.

Comment: Oil sounds like a good idea but it may cause problems with the veneer. I would contact the manufacturer before trying anything that could void the warranty.

Comment: The top layer is a laminate, not veneer. Also, the idea is to wipe off any excess which gets on the top layer.

Comment: Laminate is a layer on top of the wood it is the same thing there are plastic veneers, paper and wood. Oil could cause the wood to release the laminated layer it would be a good idea to check with the manufacturer.

Comment: Ah ok understood. Mine probably is a plastic veneer then - definitely not wood.  The shop owner told me to do this, and he's been in business for a long time.  I'm assuming he would know if it does good or bad to the veneer layer, right?

Comment: I would trust a local shop, not so much a big box store as I have them give others advice that was flat out wrong and a local code violation with both electrical and fire place inserts.

Comment: This is a small local shop, not a big store.  I will try to do a 'test' to see if the teak oil makes any difference. I'll post my results here.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't use oil, that could interfere with the boards structure. Why not use the proper sealant?

Silicone based I believe and it's supper thin, doesn't interfere with fitting at all. We always use it in kitchens, dining room, bathrooms etc. 
For example, the pic is from this page at [Wickes in the UK](http://tidd.ly/8adbcdaa) Maybe there is something similar local to you?
[image: Sealant from Wickes in the UK]